# Getting: "Document would result in an invalid XML document" error

Tags: c#, xml, linq, for-loop, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to split up a xml document into multiple smaller documents. I want to pre define a badge size (max number of nodes / document) and then insert the data into it. There are 2 possible structures of my xml data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<V2:EndInvoices">
  <V2:EndInvoice>
  </V2:EndInvoice>
  ...
 </V2:EndInvoices>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<tls:AkontoGroup">
  <tls:AkontoMember>
  </tls:AkontoMember>
  ...
 </tls:AkontoGroup>
```

Right now I'm focusing on only one case. Each `rechnungen.ToArray()[i]` element contains one of these `EndInvoice` elements. I was able to create 4 files with a input file of 20 invoices split by 5 (batchSize = 5), each file containing one `EndInvoice`. Then I moved the line `batchRechnung.Add(rechnungen.ToArray()[i]);` out of the `if` block, which now causes me the error.

```
public List<XDocument> createTemporaryXMLFiles(string pathToData, int batchSize)
{
    List<XDocument> batchRechnungen = new List<XDocument>();
    XDocument batchRechnung = new XDocument();
    XElement dataSource = XElement.Load(pathToData);
    IEnumerable<XElement> rechnungen = dataSource.Elements();

    for(int i = 0; i < rechnungen.ToArray().Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || (i % batchSize) == 0)
        {
            batchRechnung = new XDocument();
            batchRechnungen.Add(batchRechnung);
        }
        batchRechnung.Add(rechnungen.ToArray()[i]);

    }
    return batchRechnungen;
}
```

How can I get correct xml files, each containting

```
<V2:EndInvoices">
 batchSize x (<V2:EndInvoice></V2:EndInvoice>)
</V2:EndInvoices>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add multiple root elements to `XDocument`. And that's exactly what happens when you write `batchRechnung.Add`. Therefore, you must add the root element first. And then add elements to it.

```
public List<XDocument> createTemporaryXMLFiles(string pathToData, int batchSize)
{
    List<XDocument> batchRechnungen = new List<XDocument>();
    XElement dataSource = XElement.Load(pathToData);            
    XDocument batchRechnung = new XDocument(new XElement(dataSource.Name));
    var rechnungen = dataSource.Elements().ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < rechnungen.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || (i % batchSize) == 0)
        {
            batchRechnung = new XDocument(new XElement(dataSource.Name));
            batchRechnungen.Add(batchRechnung);
        }
        batchRechnung.Root.Add(rechnungen[i]);
    }
    return batchRechnungen;
}
```